# Voice Modulator Software

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, voice

I am looking for a voice modulator software that runs on OS X and converts a voice into scrambled and distorted sounding audio (like the ones in the movies).

Comment: I think you are in the wrong place.

Comment: i want a software on OS X :)

Comment: I would say to avoid the two poorly rated Mac App store voice candy and chipmunk apps as they look to be very poorly done and received. Would you be open to a custom plug in that runs in GarageBand - there are hundreds of novelty iOS apps that fit the bill, but I don't see a great selection of stand alone "spooky spy voice" apps on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use GarageBand:

- Choose for example the voice template
- Change "Monitor: Off" to On
- Add some effects (like Vocal Transformer or Bitcrusher) in the Edit tab